# Error while deploying lambda function using serverless framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, aws-serverless, aws-sam

while deploying to aws lambda I get the following error as showin in picture and text[error][1]

```
Error: `python.exe -m pip install -t C:/Users/asma/AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/fa6c9f84e92253cbebe2f17deb9708a48dc1d1d7bff853c13add0f8197336d73_x86_64_slspyc -r C:/Users/asma/AppData/Local/UnitedIncome/serverless-python-requirements/Cache/fa6c9f84e92253cbebe2f17deb9708a48dc1d1d7bff853c13add0f8197336d73_x86_64_slspyc/requirements.txt --cache-dir C:\Users\asma\AppData\Local\UnitedIncome\serverless-python-requirements\Cache\downloadCacheslspyc` Exited with code 1
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (D:\serverless project\serverless framework\timezone789\time789\venv\node_modules\child-process-ext\spawn.js:38:8)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:domain:475:12)
    at ChildProcess.cp.emit (D:\serverless project\serverless framework\timezone789\time789\venv\node_modules\cross-spawn\lib\enoent.js:34:29)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1092:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:302:5)
```

###########
my serverless.yml file is as follow:

```
org: sayyedaasma
app: zones
service: time789
frameworkVersion: '3'

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: python3.8

functions:
  hello:
    handler: handler.hello
    events:
      - httpApi:
          path: /
          method: get

plugins:
  - serverless-python-requirements
```

############# requirement.txt file is as follow

```
pytz==2022.1
```

############# handler.py file

```
import json
import pytz


def lambda_handler(event, context):
  
    l1=[]
 
    #print('Timezones')
    for timeZone in pytz.all_timezones:
        l1.append(timeZone)
    return {
        'statusCode': 200,
        'body': json.dumps(l1)
    }
```

I have followed the following tutorial.
https://www.serverless.com/blog/serverless-python-packaging/
I don't understand what is the cause of this issue since I am a beginner . Can anyone here please guide me?

Answer (score 0):

similar issues being reported here
https://github.com/serverless/serverless-python-requirements/issues/663

try this
https://github.com/serverless/serverless-python-requirements/issues/663#issuecomment-1131211339

You may try running these tutorials on either a cloud9 console or cloudshell
you will face a lot less issues in an aws environment.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is mandatory for me to use serverless framework

Comment: You will still be developing serveless framework. The comment above explains how you can use IDE in the cloud and not in your local machine. Cloud IDE has most of the aws tools pre-installed and configured. Allowing us to reduce chances of bad configuration.